# Applying 'complex' function n times and record results using data from columns of two separate dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, lapply

I have two dataframes of equal dimensions with data organized in this way (simplified replicated example, each dataframe has a significant meaning in my problem):

```
df1 <- data.frame(Col1=sample(1000,5),Col2=sample(1000,5))
df2 <- data.frame(Col1=sample(1000,5),Col2=sample(1000,5))
```

I also have a function that is relatively complex that returns a dataframe as well. The input parameters are each respective column from `df1` and `df2`. For example:

```
# if we just run the function for Col1's and other set parameters x,y,z,l,m
# USER_FUNCTION(df1col's,df2col's,x,y,z,l,m...)

> tmp <- USER_FUNCTION(df1[[1]],df2[[1]],x,y,z,l,m)

# the function spits out a dataframe with three columns A,B,C
# column A is a vector of numbers, column B is a vector of strings
# column C is vector of our future rownames
# the rownames are dates pulled from df1 and df2, and stored as strings
> tmp
            A          B           C
1        number1     string1     rownames1
2        number2     string2     rownames2
```

My current solution is to loop through `df1` and `df2` in this way:

```
newdf <- data.frame()
for(m in 1:ncol(df1)){

  tmp <- USER_FUNCTION(df1[[m]],df2[[m]],x,y,z,l,m)
  newdf <- rbind(newdf,tmp)
}
```

This allows me to create a `newdf` that contains all the results from applying `USER_FUNCTION` using the columns of `df1` and `df2` as input parameters.

The loop method is not that bad when `df1` and `df2` are 6000x250 (it roughly takes 4 seconds to complete all iterations). However, I've recently expanded my data sets to 6000x500 and it sometimes takes exponentially longer.

I am not very familiar with `apply()` type functions (or `lapply()`, `mapply()`, etc...). I was wondering if there was a more efficient method of achieving my end goal of `newdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:ncol(df1), function(m) USER_FUNCTION(df1[[m]],df2[[m]],x,y,z,l,m)))
```

Comment: excellent. I was just missing the use of do.call. This is such a simple solution and it really speeds things up